# Testing database transformation mappings

Tags: test-design, manual-testing, data-analysis, data-quality, data-warehouse-testing

If regularly testing the creation of different datawarehouse tables using mappings from source tables. What do you suggest is the best approach or specific SQLs to do the trick?

Comment: Hi toop, welcome to SQA.  You asked a broad question.   I suggest you type "data warehouse" into the search box in the upper right-hand corner of this page, hit the "Enter" key, and read some of the questions and answers listed in the search results.  After that, if you have a more specific question, feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: This product is created by my company]

We have a product call [QuerySurge](http://www.rttsweb.com/services/products/querysurge/) that allows you to fully compare data in the source tables with the data loaded into the data warehouse.  Compared to other approaches, this seems to be the best automated method for validation.

Comment: I haven't used QuerySurge, but if it does half of what it claims, it would be a VERY useful tool for data warehouse testing.